# SSIS load data between multiple tables on different server instances

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a requirement wherein I need to load data from Server A Stored Procedures (as Source) to Server B Tables.

I have 14 Stored Procedures (Source) and 14 Tables (Destination).

The Tables can have varying no of columns with 430 being the Max and 35 being the Min.

I was searching for the best way to achieve this. Here are the two possible solutions that I came across

- [Dynamic approach](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33564.ssis-transfer-data-from-multiple-tables-using-a-single-dft.aspx)
- OLE DB source and Destination for each table

The first approach will require only one table where the data will be dumped into and from there it will be moved to destination tables.However, it requires type conversion and requires all the Stored Procedure to explicitly return 430 columns so that they can be mapped to the Table which will have 430 columns.

The second approach is simple but it will make the package size long since it will have components for each table.It will also require 14 staging tables in the Server B.

I am little confused as to which approach is the best considering future maintenance.

Also, this is frequent activity and not just one time.

**Linked Server** is not an option for us.

Can some one please suggest me what should be the best way to achieve this?

Any new solution or suggestions are welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Does it have to be SSIS? I made a simple C# program using [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) for similar situation, although my sources were all tables, but procedure shouldn't be much different.

Comment: @JamesZ Yes it has to be SSIS

Comment: I have done similar processes in the past and my preference is to use the single staging table and then move the applicable data from there to its proper table. Yes, it will require the conversion and that is fine. Once you get this thing set up if you are careful with it you wont have to touch it for a very long time.